# Convert a time column with extra digits to a full time columns to hours:mins:secs

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working on a time series data frame.The df is as follows:

```
0   2019-01-01  Contact    Tuesday  False   January 04:00:00.118000 1
1   2019-01-01  Contact    Tuesday  False   January 04:00:00.483000 1
2   2019-01-01  Contact    Tuesday  False   January 08:00:00.162000 1
3   2019-01-01  Contact    Tuesday  False   January 08:00:00.426000 1
4   2019-01-01  Contact    Tuesday  False   January 08:00:00.564000 1
```

To get this df I have done other transformation above hence, this is not a direct load.
so I am trying to convert the second last column with `04:00:00.118000` to `04:00:00`.
What is the quickest way to achieve this?

Comment: From your question, I assume you have tried `pd.to_datetime` and you can't use it because the `1` at the end is also a part of the column?

Comment: the 1 is another column. I want to split and drop the remaining part of the time. The delimiter has to be a full stop. How do I  achieve that?

Comment: @DerrickKuria, What is the column type for `January 04:00:00.118000 1` this data?

Comment: its an object Datatype 
dtype('O')

Comment: @DerrickKuria, See i have mimic'd the data and for me its also `object` , so place the simple solution which should work taking the data in consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entries in the second to last column are of type `datetime.time`, you could use the following:

```
df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda t: t.replace(microsecond=0))
```

where `name` is the name of your second to last column. If they are of type `str`, then you could use this instead:

```
df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda t: t.split('.')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you have the Object type data then it should work..

### Sample data mimicking the data ..

```
>>> df
                      date  col1
0  January 04:00:00.118000     1
1  January 04:00:00.483000     1
2  January 08:00:00.162000     1
3  January 08:00:00.426000     1
>>> df.dtypes
date    object
col1     int64
dtype: object
```

### Solution

```
>>> df['date'] = df['date'].str.split(".").str[0]
>>> df
               date  col1
0  January 04:00:00     1
1  January 04:00:00     1
2  January 08:00:00     1
3  January 08:00:00     1
```